# how to add autocomplete="off" property to field in drupal registration form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, autocomplete

hi
i enable Profile module and create 3 field in registration form.
but i want add autocomplete="off" property to input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) in your custom module.

Example:

```
<?php
function mycustommodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register') {
    $form['category_name']['profile_fieldname']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';
  }
}
?>
```

- Where `category_name` is the name of your profile fields category exactly as written in the **Field settings > Category**.
- Where `profile_fieldname` is the name of your field exactly as written in the **Field settings > Form name**.

Comment: This may overwrite any additional attributes other modules have on this form element, so I recommend using:

$form['category_name']['profile_fieldname']['#attributes']['autocomplete'] = 'off';

Comment: Thanks @Dave Reid. Edited the answer as per your note.

Comment: Even though it's not the question that was originally asked, this answer doesn't work on password fields. See the #process example in http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/disabling-autocomplete-forms for details on how to handle passwords and cck phones and other fields that need to have a #process on them to add this attribute.